# Include issue with XLL plus

Tags: c++, visual-studio, xll, stdafx.h

Trying to create and run a new XLL+ project. When the project gets created. No error, however, if I turn the Active Solution Platform to x64 in Visual Studio 2015, I get the following error:

```
Error   C1189   #error:  include 'stdafx.h' before including this file for PCH
```

Anyone would know how to solve this?

Best regards,
A.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and received the following response from the helpful Planatech support team:

In brief:

1. Replace the faulty 64-bit platform settings by deleting them and
   then cloning the x86 platform settings.
2. For each build, set
   ForceSymbolReferences to DllMain.

In detail:

1) Remove the faulty 64-bit Solution settings

- a) Click on the menu command: Build / Configuration Manager.
- b) In the Configuration Manager dialog, click on the "Active solution platform" combo-box and select "Edit..."
- c) In the Edit Solution Platforms dialog, select "x64" in the list, and press the "Remove" button.
- d) Click "Yes" in the confirmation dialog.
- e) Click "Close" in the Edit Solution Platforms dialog.

2) Remove the faulty 64-bit Project settings

- a) Still in the Configuration Manager dialog, in the projects grid,
  drop down the "Platform" combo box in the first row, and select
  "Edit...".
- b) In the Edit Project Platforms dialog, select "x64" in
  the list, and press the "Remove" button.
- c) Click "Yes" in the
  confirmation dialog.
- d) Click "Close" in the Edit Project Platforms
  dialog.

3) Create new 64-bit settings

- a) Still in the Configuration Manager dialog, click on the "Active solution platform" combo-box and select "New...".
- b) In the New Solution Platform dialog, select "x64" in the list for the new platform, set "Copy settings from:" to "x86", put a check against "Create new project platforms" and press the "OK" button.
- c) In the Configuration Manager dialog, click on the "Active solution platform" combo-box and select "x64"
- d) Close the Configuration Manager dialog.

4) Fix the link settings

- a) Use the Project / Properties menu command to open the Project Property Pages window.
- b) Set Configuration to "All Configurations" and ensure that Platform is set to "x64".
- c) In the left hand side tree, select the node: "Configuration Properties / Linker / Input". Force Symbol References will contain "_DllMain%4012;%(ForceSymbolReferences)". Change it to "**DllMain**;%(ForceSymbolReferences)".
- d) Press OK to save changes and close the window.

The 64-bit platform settings are now complete, and you will be able to build both Release and Debug.